# Winforms datarepeater doesn't swipe scroll on a touchscreen

Tags: c#, winforms, datarepeater

I'm using the datarepeater that comes with the visual basic power pack in a winforms application.  The problem I'm having is that the control doesn't allow swiping inside the container to scroll up and down.  You can still use the scroll bar itself, but the width of the scroll bar is too skinny and is hard to get a hold of sometimes.  This baffles me, because swipe scrolling on all the other winforms controls seems to work fine.  This is probably a longshot, but can anybody help me?

Comment: WinForms + touch = "Good luck"

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Honestly, I haven't run into any issues until I started using the data repeater.  Maybe a WPF control would work better?

Comment: It would certainly work better with touch. To make matters worse, you are using a VB power pack control, which is even *less* likely to work. WinForms is out of date, and they didn't anticipate a lot of the current stuff. I don't know the answer, but I'm not surprised you are having issues

Comment: For anyone else looking at this problem, I'm going to be using the DevExpress hybrid winforms controls: https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Touch.xml